# Private Git on OpenShift

Tags: git, openshift

Is any way to configure a private git repository in OpenShift?

Or OpenShift doesn't provide external access to Git repositories?

Comment: "a private github repository in OpenShift" ? You mean "a private *git* repository in OpenShift"

Comment: As I know, OpenShift git repository is accessible only for you and your team (in non-free plans).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to execute the following steps:

```
git clone <your-external-repo-url>
change to newly cloned git directory
git remote add openshift -f <openshift-git-repo-url>
git merge openshift/master -s recursive -X ours

git push openshift master
```

Here's the [reference](https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/2013/02/openshift-use-external-git-repository-with-openshift/)

Comment: Good to mention that `<your-external-repo-url>` is gained from the output of `rhc show-app MYAPP | grep 'Git URL:'`

Answer (score 0):

[Akram Ben Aissi published an interesting post in the Openshift blog](https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-gitlab-openshift/) about how to deploy Gitlab in Openshift v3.

I saw it very useful, maybe could be interesting if someone is looking for a recent update or this question.

Very easy, create 3 new apps for postgress, redis and gitce and at the end add a persistent volumes:

Postgresql:

```
oc new-app --template=postgresql-persistent \
-p POSTGRESQL_USER=admin,POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=redhat,POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=gitlab
```

Redis

```
oc new-app  sameersbn/redis
oc volume dc/redis --add --overwrite -t persistentVolumeClaim \
                    --claim-name=redis-data --name=redis-volume-1 \
                    --mount-path=/var/lib/redis
```

Get redis and postgresql services IPs to be passed to git-ce container (in this case 172.30.25.83, 172.30.198.140)

```
oc get svc postgresql redis
```

Git-ce container

```
oc new-app sameersbn/gitlab --name=gitlab-ce 
                         -e 'GITLAB_HOST=http://gitlab.apps.mycompany.com' \
                         -e 'DB_TYPE=postgres' -e 'DB_HOST=172.30.25.83' \ 
                         -e 'DB_PORT=5432'    -e 'DB_NAME=gitlab'   -e 'DB_USER=admin' \
                         -e 'DB_PASS=admin'   -e 'REDIS_HOST=172.30.198.140 -e 'REDIS_PORT=6379' \
                         -e 'GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=1234567890' -e 'SMTP_ENABLED=true' \
                         -e 'SMTP_HOST=smtp.mycompany.com' -e 'SMTP_PORT=25' \
                         -e 'GITLAB_EMAIL=no-reply@mycompany.com'
```

Configure persistent volumes:

```
oc volumes dc/gitlab-ce --add --claim-name=gitlab-log --mount-path=/var/log/gitlab \
                 -t persistentVolumeClaim --overwrite
oc volumes dc/gitlab-ce --add --claim-name=gitlab-data --mount-path=/home/git/data \
                 -t persistentVolumeClaim --overwrite
```

Comment: As links can change over time, it is much better to include the pertinent informtation in your answer and just provide the link for context. Could you edit your answer to do that? Thanks and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
oc new-app http:<git url>
```

If you require providing credentials to the git repository, then it will require a bit more effort. You'll need to associate the appropriate secrets for access associated with the build configuration, details can be found [here](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds.html#adding-secrets-to-source-strategy-build-configs).